# Will creating new array clear the whole php session data?

Tags: php, session, arrays

Code below:

```
$_SESSION = array();
```

Will it clear all session data? If I wouldn't want to use session_destory().

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yup, it will destroy all session data but not the session itself.

Basically, there's three elements to a session:

- The session itself, initialized with `session_start()`
- The session cookie which is set automatically
- Session data which is set via `$_SESSION['foo'] = 'bar'`

So you are only destroying the session data. `session_destroy()` destroys both the data and the session itself, but does not remove the session cookie.

The only "real" difference between `$_SESSION = array()` and `session_destroy()` is that after `session_destroy()`, setting session data will not work anymore before initializing a new session.

Comment: It's akin to saying that $_SESSION = array(); will /reset/ the session whereas session_destory() /removes/ it.

Answer (score -2):

[Yes](http://php.net/session-destroy), setting `$_SESSION` to a blank array will essentially unset all existing array keys.